# How can I compare dates of format yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS in javascript while the inputs are of charecter format

Tags: javascript

How can I compare dates of format yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS in javascript while the inputs are of charecter format.I tried using date parse and other things.No luck

Comment: share us what u have tried. good luck :)

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what you exactly want?

Comment: If they are formatted as `yyyyMMdd HHmmss.SSS` and are in the same timezone, they should be comparable to one another as strings. With what are you trying to compare them? With one another?

Comment: var a="A";
        var b="N";
        //To check if datemodified is greater than lsr
        var n= new Date(l);
        var n1 = new Date(ls);
        if (n>n1) {
       //size check
       if(i1<524288000)
       {
       out=a;}}
       else {
       out=b;
       }

Comment: @suryaamalaVungarala—please do not recommend parsing non-standard strings with the built-in parser, it is a seriously bad idea. `new Date('20170531 131515.765');` returns `Invalid Date` in IE and Chrome at least (and probably most other implementations too).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert your dates to ISO-8601 format and load them using new Date() and compare the dates.

The other way is to use 3rd party libs like Moment js (momentjs.com/docs/).

```
var m1 = moment(dateStr1, 'YYYYMMDD HHmmss.SSS');
var m2 = moment(dateStr2, 'YYYYMMDD HHmmss.SSS'); 

if (m1 == m2) {}
```

Using plain JS

```
function toDate(d) {
    var regex = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\s(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.(\d{3})/;

    var YEAR = 1, MONTH=2, DAY=3, HOUR=4, MIN=5, SEC=6;
    var parts = date.match(regex);
    return new Date(`${parts[YEAR]}-${parts[MONTH]}-${parts[DAY] ${parts[HOUR]}:${parts[MIN]}:${parts[SEC]}`);
}

var d1 = toDate('20170531 131515.765');
```

Comment: sorry, missed it :)

Comment: Hi bugs_cena. RobG.. I cannot use moment related functions.IS there any other way?

Comment: @suryaamalaVungarala—you can write your own parser, not difficult.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to parse the string to generate another string that must be parsed again by the (problematic) built-in parser. YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss is parsed as UTC by Safari but local by others, so **much** better to feed the bits directly to the Date constructor and avoid the built-in parser altogether. ;-)

Comment: @RobG yes, that would be the best way to do it. But here in this case, it looks like the date string itself is in a custom format, so, without converting it to a better format by parsing, there's no other way of comparing the dates? The best solution would be for the server to return it in a standard format.

Comment: @bugs_cena—yes, I'm just saying better to do `new Date(parts[YEAR], parts[MONTH] - 1, ...)`. I guess for comparison it doesn't matter if they're UTC or local since it's the relative value that matters. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If by "compare dates" you mean if date1 is before date2 (i.e. `<` or `>` operators), the format you have will let you compare as strings:

```js
var a = '20170531 231253.475';
var b = '20170531 231254.000';

console.log('a is before b? ' + (a.localeCompare(b) < 0));
console.log('b is before a? ' + (b.localeCompare(a) < 0));
```

If you want to compare them as Dates, you can parse the strings fairly easily:

```js
var a = '20170531 231253.475';
var b = '20170531 231254.000';

// Parse date string in format yyyymmdd HHmmss.SSS
function parseSpecial(t) {
  var y = t.substr(0,4);
  var m = t.substr(4,2);
  var d = t.substr(6,2);
  var h = t.substr(9,2);
  var M = t.substr(11,2);
  var s = t.substr(13,2);
  var S = t.substr(16,3);
  return new Date(y, m-1, d, h, M, s, S);
}
console.log('a is: ' + parseSpecial(a).toString() +
          '\nb is: ' + parseSpecial(b).toString());
console.log('Is a before b? ' + (parseSpecial(a) < parseSpecial(b)));
console.log('Is b before a? ' + (parseSpecial(b) < parseSpecial(a)));
```

Of course you should add validation to the parser to ensure you're comparing valid dates and provide default values for any missing parts.